# How to run a macro in emacs slow speeds?

Tags: emacs, macros

How to run a macro in emacs slow speeds? That is, the macro runs very fast, I wanted to control the speed to run slower.
F3 - F4 run macro in slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the manual:

[You can interactively replay ... the last keyboard macro, one command at a time, by typing <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-k</kbd> <kbd>SPC</kbd> (kmacro-step-edit-macro)](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Keyboard-Macro-Step_002dEdit.html)

You'll have to manually initiate each step by typing <kbd>SPC</kbd> or <kbd>y</kbd>, but that's probably more useful than just watching the macro go by in slow motion. Type <kbd>?</kbd> for more details.